# Formula to sort by column that contains times and text, place text at the end, in Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

My Google Sheets `Select` statement selects rows from a master sheet of results and then sorts them by time (least amount of time first) ascending.

Some of these results will be entered as DNS and I want them to appear at the end of the time but they appear at the top.

Here is my statement:

```
Select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,V,W where not D contains '/' and O is not Null order by P Asc
```

Column P contains time in `HH:mm:ss` formatted as duration. If one of the riders is a DNS, they appear at the top of the sort.  Unless I sort descending - which is not desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With *DNS*, you probably mean "did not start". The `query()` function will only accept one data type in a column, and because most of the values in column `P` are time values, the "DNS" values will return as null. `query()` sorts `null` values first.

Try this to sort your data the way you describe:

```
=sort( { Data!A2:R, Data!Q2:R, Data!V2:W }, Data!P2:P, true )
```

Then use `filter()` or `query()` to remove rows where column `D` contains a `/`.